# Update RecyclerView Adapter while scrolling it results in crash

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my `RecyclerView` (`notifyDataSetChanged`or any other "`changed`" method) which contains many view types, but if happens while the user is scrolling, it results in crash.

The message of the crash is that a `ViewHolder` cannot be cast to another.

Example

> java.lang.ClassCastException: package.adapters.Adapter$AlphabetViewHolder cannot be cast to package.adapters.Adapter$NumbersViewHolder

My question is: how can I update a `RecyclerView` while the user is scrolling it? Is there anything special that I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement observer pattern and some function in your adapter to tell the observer(in this case the activity) when to provide more data based on the position of your items.

```
interface ScrollObserver {

    fun notifyLoadMore(num: Int): Unit
}
```

```
class MainActivity: ScrollObserver {

...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        adapter.scrollObserver = this
    }

    override fun notifyLoadMore(num: Int) {
        loadMoreData(num)
        updateRecyclerView()
    }

}
```

in your adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuestionViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    if (isTimeToLoadMore(position)) {
        scrollObserver.notifyLoadMore(position)
    }
```

you need to implement `isTimeToLoadMore` based on your requirements. the classes are simplified and definitely doesn't work with copy-pasting. but I hope you get the idea.
you can observe the adapter with viewmodel pretty much the same way!